# Getting errors to display just the exception without all the added program info

Tags: c#

I have an error like this :

```
unable to perform backup.....System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
manifest     
definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxApi.ParseJson[T](String json)
   at Dropbox.Api.DropboxApi.GetFiles(String root, String path)
 at AndroBackupUtility.Form1.inc_filekeep() in
c:\Users\shanem.CAN\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Andromeda
backup\Main\AndroBackupUtility\AndroBackupUtility\Form1.cs:line 270
at AndroBackupUtility.Form1.dropboxup(String curbackdir, String backupfilename, String
logfile, String foldname) in c:\Users\shanem.CAN\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Andromeda
Backup\Main\AndroBackupUtility\AndroBackupUtility\Form1.cs:line 399
at AndroBackupUtility.Form1.inc_backup() in
c:\Users\shanem.CAN\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Andromeda
Backup\Main\AndroBackupUtility\AndroBackupUtility\Form1.cs:line 239
at AndroBackupUtility.Form1.incremental_Elapsed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\Users\shanem.CAN\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Andromeda
Backup\Main\AndroBackupUtility\AndroBackupUtility\Form1.cs:line 144
```

What I would like is to cut the error down to something like :

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or Assembly
```

how could I manage that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, assuming you have an exception `ex`:

```
string.Format("{0}: {1}", ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
```

Note that it will still leave the entire message, so you'll get:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

There's not a standard way of cutting it down any shorter - you could just truncate it, but that might not leave enough information for some messages.